# multi bit clock converged to single bit using type casting

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I tried to convert multiple bits to single bit using type casting method, but lint checker (LEDA) is not allowing `[0:0]` and points it as error. Does `[0:0]` means an array still?

Code used:

```
module xyz(
  input        x,
  input      rst,
  input      din,
  output reg dout
);

  logic [1:0] i_clk;
  logic [0:0]   clk;

  assign i_clk = logic'(x    );
  assign clk   = logic'(i_clk);

  always_ff @(posedge clk) begin 
    if (rst) 
      dout <= '0;
    else 
      dout <= din; 
  end

endmodule
```

LEDA Design checker command line:

```
leda -top xyz filename.v -config leda_config.tcl +v2k -sverilog
```

leda_config.tcl:

```
rule_deselect -all rule_select -rule W450
```

Error looks like:

```
 Multi-bit expression (e.g., a[2:0]) used as clock
```

Comment: What kind of error? I couldn't recreate it with software I use.

Comment: Lint error(you can use any Linting tool) multi bit expression used as clock

Comment: logic is a System verilog defination , its not in verilog .Are you sure you are compiling with -sv ??

Comment: yes I am compiling with systemverilog switches here I am posted because its not allowing me to add systemverilog tag here. Not sure why it requires 1500 rep to post as systemverilog?

Comment: consider using LEDA Design checker, leda -top xyz filename.v -config leda_config.tcl +v2k -sverilog
in config I am having rule_deselect -all
rule_select -rule W450  I am sure spyglass too supports this Error looks like Multi-bit expression (e.g., a[2:0]) used as clock

Comment: What do you want from  `assign clk = logic'(i_clk);` ?

Comment: If the signals are multibit I am converting back it to single bit as clk is necessarily a single bit for synthesizable purpose, but as you mentioned [0:0] is a single bit, but tool says it as multi bit, this brings a doubt

Comment: I am still not clear what does 'converting back it to single bit' mean. Do you want the LSB, the MSB, the OR of the 2 bits or the AND of the 2 bits. How do you want to convert back to 1 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Many tools have problems with `logic clk` versus `logic [0:0] clk`. Technically, the former is a scalar variable and the latter is an array of one element, Unfortunately, many tools have incorrectly allowed you to make references to `clk[0]` or `clk[0:0]` even though it was declared as `logic clk;`, so the way tools react to the different declarations or references become muddled.